# ¿Por qué nos quedamos con la forma "sandio" y no con "sandío", tras siglos de coexistencia de ambas?

Tags: etimología, historia, ortografía, acentuación, lingüística

La palabra [**SANDIO**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XC1aEei) aparece escrita sin tilde en los diccionarios que se pueden consultar a través del NTTLE.

Sin embargo, el CORDE muestra que durante unos 300 años coexistía la forma con tilde en la **i** - por ejemplo en el Fuero Juzgo (1250 - 1260):

> ... quál es el omne tan **sandío** que corte su cabeça con su mano ...

o en el Fuero Real (1251 - 1260):

> ... alguno non fuere de edat, o fuere **sandío**, o en prisión, non pierda su heredat ...

y otros ejemplos hasta mediados del siglo XVI, como en Rodríguez Florián, Juan (1554) (Comedia llamada Florinea, que tracta de los amores del buen duque Floriano con la linda y muy casta ...)

> ... a él tuviera por **sandío** en pasar tal como a ella tengo por cruel ...

con la forma sin tilde, que es la que ha prevalecido.

¿Hay alguna razón que explique que tras tanto tiempo de coexistencia se fijara la forma sin tilde y desapareciera la forma con tilde?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be being misled by the transcription in CORDE's database. Accents were not generally used in Spanish until the 16th century:

> In general, the accent mark was not employed in manuscripts in Spanish or Spanish books before 1550. It was only after the Italian and French models had been created that the widespread use of accent marks began to be practiced in Spanish. Between 1475 (the approximate date of the introduction of printing into Spain) and 1566, the use of accent marks was negligible

So it seems likely that the editions of these works CORDE has scanned are from a later copy than the early handwritten manuscripts.

## 1. Orthography: Coexistence of *sandío* and *sandio* given the common pronunciation `/san'dio/`

Spanish's history of accents prior to the 19th century is a long, complicated, and often contradictory affair. Limiting ourselves to discussion of *llana* words ending *-io/-ío*, the ambiguities with stress are thus:

> When the last syllable of a noun or a verb contained a non-Latin diphthong (the
>   only Classical Latin diphthongs had been *oe* and *ae*, and many new diphthongs had been created in Vulgar Latin and in Spanish itself), a new problem developed: what about a word like *diferencia*, which by Classical Latin rules
>   could be accented on the final *i*, because it constituted a separate syllable? Should it be spelled *diferéncia* or should the modern language accept the notion of the diphthongs that had developed as early as Vulgar Latin times?

We note that in the  *"Discurso proemial de la orthographia"* (*Discurso*) of the first *Diccionario* (1726), "the first statement on correctness of Spanish spelling by an official governing body" they did not address this question at all:

> It is interesting to note that, even with all the fuss concerning long vowels, very basic questions were not addressed, such as the issue of how to show stress on words like *diferencia* and *mengua* as opposed to *vacío* and *evalúa*... The authors of the *Discurso* simply ignored the issue altogether.

This ambiguity can be seen in the frequent inconsistency among even the writers of the *Discurso* itself in treatment of accents on such words:

> The treatment of paroxytones is quite chaotic. We find *calidades* and *calidádes* on the very same page just a few lines apart. Not so close are *comúnes* and *divisiones*, ***solía* and *dia*,** *principáles* and *universales*. In each of these pairs of words the identical pattern of vowels and consonants occurs with the identical pattern of accentuation; but half of them have accents and half of them do not. The words *orígen* and *léngua* always have a written accent. **Words ending in diphthongs *-io* or *-ia* usually carried an accent on the preceding stressed vowel, as in *necessários*, *princípio*, *próprios*, and *observáncia*, but we also find *ignorancia* and *diferencia*.**

So, given all this, it is unsurprising that there is a mix of orthographies for *sandío/sandio* in the CORDE's register:

[image]

Indeed, looking at the NTLLE, we see that even within dictionary headers, usage is inconsistent year on year (even within the same publishing bodies) until the second half of the 19th century:

> - sandio   1495 NEBRIJA
> - ...
> - sandio    1611 COVARRUBIAS
> - **sandío**    1611 ROSAL
> - sandio    1617 MINSHEU
> - sandio    1620 FRANCIOSINI
> - sandio    1670 MEZ DE BRAIDENBACH
> - **sándio**    1705 SOBRINO
> - **sandío**    1706 STEVENS
> - sandio    1721 BLUTEAU
> - sandio    1739 ACADEMIA AUTORIDADES (S-Z)
> - **sándio**    1780 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - sandio    1783 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - ...
> - sandio    1803 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - **sandío**    1817 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - **sándio**    1822 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - sandio    1825 NÚÑEZ DE TABOADA
> - ...
> - sandio    1846 SALVÁ
> - **sándio**    1852 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - sandio    1853 DOMÍNGUEZ
> - **sándio**    1855 GASPAR Y ROIG (G-Z)
> - sandio    1869 ACADEMIA USUAL
> - ...
> - sandio    1992 ACADEMIA USUAL

## 2. Pronunciation: `/san'dio/` → `/'sandjo/`

This still leaves us with the question of, assuming it was originally pronounced `/san'dio/`, how it came to be pronounced `/'sandjo/` (and thus why the spelling *sandío* fell out of use).

As per the NTLLE search, it seems the `/'sandjo/` pronunciation existed since at least the start of the 18th century (and possibly much earlier). Assuming this pronunciation was a later development, there is ample precedent for such a shift. Consider the following:

> **b). Diptongo (*Hiato*), (62):**
>
> carau (caraú), balaustre (balaústre), bronquiolo (bronquíolo),
>
> acedia (acedía), ademprio (ademprío), agrafia (agrafía), elefancia (elefancía),
>
> aeromancia (aeromancía), alectomancia (alectomancía), bibliomancia (bibliomancía), capnomancia (capnomancía), cartomancia (cartomancía), catoptromancia (catoptromancía), ceraunomancia (ceraunomancía), ceromancia (ceromancía), demonomancia (demonomancía), espatulomancia (espatulomancía), exoftalmia (exoftalmía), geomancia (geomancía), heteromancia (heteromancía), hidromancia (hidromancía), lecanomancia (lecanomancía), necromancia (necromancía), oniromancia (oniromancía), onomancia (onomancía), ornitomancia (ornitomancía), piromancia (piromancía), quiromancia (quiromancía),  uromancia (uromancía),
>
> oftalmia (oftalmía), xeroftalmia (xeroftalmía),
>
> -plastia (-plastía (Amér)), hernioplastia (hernioplastía),
>
> cuadriplejia (cuadriplejía), hemiplejia (hemiplejía), paraplejia (paraplejía), tetraplejia (tetraplejía),
>
> -scopia (-scopía (Amér)), endoscopia (endoscopía (Amér)), gastroscopia (gastroscopía (Amér)), microscopia (microscopía),
>
> olimpiada (olimpíada), paralimpiada (paralimpíada), parolimpiada (parolimpíada),
>
> amoniaco (amoníaco), armoniaco (armoníaco (desus)), austriaco (austríaco), bosniaco (bosníaco), cardiaca (cardíaca (Amér)), cordiaco (cordíaco (desus)) egipciaco (egipcíaco), isiaco (isíaco), lipemaniaco (lipemaníaco), monomaniaco (monomaníaco), olimpiaco (olimpíaco (desus)), peloponesiaco (peloponesíaco), simoniaco (simoníaco), siriaco (siríaco), zodiaco (zodíaco).
>
> - [*Cambios de acento en español*](http://www.academia.edu/26337322/Cambios_de_acento_en_espa%C3%B1ol), Alcoba Rueda (p.450-451)

etc

---

Sources:

- [*Written Accents in Spanish to 1726*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/343313?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Douglass (1988)
- [*The evolution of the written accentuation system in Spanish
  since 1726*](http://ojs.ub.gu.se/ojs/index.php/modernasprak/article/download/1237/1935), Coughlin, Morin (2013)

Answer (score 1):

El tema de la coexistencia de las formas con o sin tilde supongo que estará relacionado con las variaciones y *titubeos* ortográficos que tuvo la lengua en el pasado (y en realidad sigue teniendo, con las reformas ortográficas periódicas que impone la RAE). Creo que el tema interesante es más bien por qué antes se **pronunciaba** “san**dí**o” y hoy “**san**dio”.

Como apunta ukemi, originalmente no hubo coexistencia de ambas formas. La palabra se acentuó en la **í** desde el principio; en la literatura siempre se la hace rimar (o asonar) en la **í** (con *río*, *rocío*, *judío*, *quadrillos*, *contigo*, *castillo*, etc.) y nunca en la **a**.

Hacia principios del s. XVI la palabra ya estaba anticuada. Juan de Valdés escribe que “en Castilla no se usa agora” y Covarrubias la pone como “vocablo español antiguo, desusado”.

Pero se seguía usando en los libros de caballería arcaizantes. Por eso Cervantes la pone muchas veces en boca de Don Quijote, aunque fuera tan artificial, ya en ese entonces, como decir *fermoso* y *desfazer entuertos*.

Y fue por esta inclusión de Cervantes que la palabra volvió a divulgarse entre los cultos, aunque, cortado el hilo oral, lo hizo con la acentuación cambiada, por influencia de `zafio`, `necio` y el antónimo de `sabio`. En el [original](http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/cervante/dqsb1.htm), ninguna palabra terminada en `ío` (hiato) lleva tilde en la `í`, ni ninguna terminada en `io` (diptongo) lleva tilde en alguna sílaba anterior. Si uno no sabe de antemano cómo se pronuncian, hay que elegir al azar.

(Algo parecido le ocurrió a `maguer`, que fue *rescatada* por los *hipsters* de fines del s. XVIII, pero mal, como `magüer`.)

Fuente: Corominas y Pascual. *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispano.*

Comment: Efectivamente, tiene usted razón: _endereçar tuertos y desfazer agravios_.